# Talend 7.1 tFileOutputExcel corrupt file

Tags: excel, talend

I'm trying to output an excel file from Talend 7.1. I've tried a few different setups and both xls and xlsx formats but they all result in the output file being corrupt and not being able to open it.

What am I doing wrong? I am loading an xlsx file into a database and this part works fine but outputting to excel I just can't figure it out! I was writing from the tMap directly to the tFileOutputExcel and it wasn't working (corrupt) so I changed it to write to a csv file first and then write that csv to the tFileOutputExcel but it is still corrupt.

This is my job detail:
[image: Job detail]

And this is the settings in the tFileOutputExcel
[image: tFileOutputExcel settings]

Comment: What is the extension of the excel file being generated ?

Comment: @IbrahimMezouar the output file has the correct extension (.xls) or .xlsx if the 2007 format box is selected. I've tried both formats.

Comment: @m_grif, Are you open to using external components ? The component suite for Excel by Jlolling is much better than the standard components.

Comment: @Carassus ok, i'll check that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by changing the transfer mode in the FTP component from 'ascii' to 'binary'. Such a simple thing but if this helps anyone else with this issue who is a newb like me :)